# caused by: Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined

Tags: angular

I created the component and html file. In component I defined one model and combo box values. In html file I am trying to bind those model values to text box and combo box. 
When I ran the application controls was displayed correctly but in combo box did not have any values and model was shows the undefined.
Please verify below code.

component.ts:

```
export class Testpagesearchcomponent implements OnInit {

    model: any = {};
    search_Master_cmbtest = {
        ValidValues: [
            { display: '1', value: 'a' },
            { display: '2', value: 'b' }
        ],
        DefaultValue: { display: '1', value: 'a' }
    };

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private patientService: TestpageService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.initModel();
    }

    private initModel() {
        this.model = {
            firstname: "avc",             
            cmbtest: null
        };
    }       
}
```

Html file:

```
<div class="col-sm-4" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': formsearch.firstname.$invalid }">
    <input type="text"
         class="form-control text-left"
         name="firstname"
         maxlength="50"
         [(ngModel)]="model.firstname" />
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4"> 
    <select name="cmbtest"
         class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.cmbtest">
        <option *ngFor="let option of search_Master_cmbtest.ValidValues" [ngValue]="option">{{option.display}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Where in your code are you referring to firstname? aside for where you define it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line that is causing you an error is:

```
<div class="col-sm-4" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': formsearch.firstname.$invalid }">
```

It cannot read the `firstname` of `formsearch`, that is what the error points to in this case, not your model.

If this is not a form, you should remove that and you are all good to go! :)

If this is indeed a form, you need to take a look at your validation. If you want validation for your `firstname`, I would suggest that you do this:

```
<form #formsearch="ngForm">
    <input type="text"
       name="firstname"
       maxlength="50" #firstname ngModel
       [(ngModel)]="model.firstname" required />
       <small *ngIf="!firstname.valid">Not valid!</small>
    <!-- rest of your form -->
</form>
```

Where you should note the following lines:

```
#firstname ngModel
```

With the above we bind the `name="firstname"` in the form so that the following line will work:

```
<small *ngIf="!firstname.valid">Not valid!</small>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Express 4.16+, add this code below the app initialization

```js
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use(express.json()) // To parse the incoming requests with JSON payloads
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? The question is about Angular.